# Python-Firebase printing multiple times

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a script using [python-firebase](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2):

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://<my-firebase-id>.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get('/status/time', None)
print result
```

Everything works as intended (displaying the word "time"), except that it prints it in 6 different lines, like so:

```
time
time
time
time
time
time
[Finished in 3.3s]
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: You've included a picture of the text in your question. Please replace that with the actual text, which you can easily get by copying it from your console/terminal. Having the text makes it searchable and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, I made the requested changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled with Python 3.4 instead of Python 2.7 as I was previously using, solving my problem.